# Can't get my Analytical badge

Tags: support, badges

I have just visited every page in the FAQ, hoping to get my 1st badge. But it didn't reward me one. Can someone tell me how to get the badge?

Comment: You got your badge

Answer (score 8):

Often, the system does not calculate badges immediately, but only after a delay. This is because a constant recalculation will tax the servers heavily. Therefore, you must wait until the next refresh for badges to show. Also, if after some time, you do not see your badge, clear your browser's cache.